# Gamepad changes descriptors if it's connected to an OTG port vs normal USB host port, but how does it know?

Tags: usb, otg

I have an MSI Force GC20 gamepad. It has several different "modes" which can be selected which basically allow it to reset and offer different USB descriptors. For example, it can be several variations of HID or an XInput (literally using the XBox controller descriptor verbatim).

When I plug the controller into my desktop PC, it always enumerates with the Xbox descriptors. I also have an embedded target, an STM32F767, which is running the ST USB host stack. I wrote a device class driver which works great with an XInput XBox controller, but the trouble is that this controller refuses to enumerate with these descriptors when connected to the Stm32F7, and instead will only use it's HID descriptors.

Using wireshark to probe the USB interactions on my desktop, the very first thing that occurs is the descriptors request, which is satisfied with the XBox descriptors. There's nothing too interesting going on before then.

I thought this could be the case that the controller was somehow determining some difference in ports because on the Stm32F7 VBus is switched off when the port is inactive. So, I changed the code such that VBus is always on. No change. I am using an off the shelf USB OTG host adapter. This should ground the ID pin and make no further changes to anything electrically (AFAIK). So I'm at a loss for how the controller is figuring out there is a difference.

My question is, what part of the USB OTG or host spec could the controller be using to make this early determination what descriptors to return? Potentially some configuration of pullup/down res on the USB 2.0 pair?

This is the Wireshark capture from my desktop:
[image]
[image]

Comment: At what point in the enumeration are the descriptors different? Right at the start with the device descriptor, or later on with one of the other descriptors?

Comment: Other than the very basic device descriptor, USB devices have dozens of other descriptors defining various alternative functions. Apparently your hand-made driver is unaware of the special functionality. OTG host or non-OTG host have no difference, all the difference is in the device driver.

Comment: @brhans Right at the very first exchange they're different. So it's something pretty fundamental

Comment: @Ale..chenski I am aware of the complete descriptor picture, with all interfaces present. When the device changes it's descriptors, the entire thing is different, it's not just selecting the wrong interface. More over, this is not a composite USB device.

Comment: Are you sure it's an 'OTG vs Normal Host' issue and not a 'Full-Speed vs High-Speed' issue? Maybe your gamepad enumerates as a 'Xbox360 Controller' to a High-Speed host, but as a HID device to a Full-Speed host...